# Using bitwise & (AND) in ViewHolder.icon.setImageBItmap

Tags: android-viewholder, bitwise-and

I was watching Google's I/O video on ViewHolder, but I'm lost on line 17. It looks like:

```
    if (position & 1) {
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
    } else {
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon2);
    }
```

What is the importance of `if (position & 1)`

```
1 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
2 ViewHolder holder;
3
4 if (convertView == null) {
5 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);
6
7 holder = new ViewHolder();
8 holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
9 holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
10
11 convertView.setTag(holder);
12 } else {
13 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
14 }
15
16 holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
17 holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);
18 
19 return convertView;
20 }
```

Slide 13
https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_0230_TurboChargeYourUI-HowtomakeyourAndroidUIfastandefficient.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA&t=10m14s

Comment: &1 is equivalent of %2, to distinguish even and odd numbers. When compiled with modern compilers they are basically the same, but some old timers, me included, prefer &1. Same thing for &0x03 is %4, &0xff is %256.